# javascript dojo toolkit using global object in application

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a mappping application like google maps api. In this application I am creating different modules. Most of my modules are using a **Map** object that is basemap in application.

For example:

**module1**

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"], function(declare){
  return declare(null, {
    constructor: function(){
         //..... use map .....
    }
  });
});
```

**module2**

**module3**

**.....**

**and Main Application Start**

```
require(["dojo/ready", "my/module1"], function(ready, fx){
     ready(function(){
           var map = new MyMap(); // this will use in other modules
     });
});
```

I can call module2 in module3 or module3 in module4, but most of these are using **map** object in created in main module.

I am passing the map object to the modules in constructor level. Is there a practical way for these stuations in dojo or javascript?

Answer (score 1):

This is the practical way. I mean, this is how you do it in any language, not only in Dojo. If one object needs another one, you add it as a property/field and set it.

The only thing you could do is move the `new MyMap()` code to a seperate module and load that module in module1, module2, module3, ... . That way the main application doesn't need to provide the dependencies.